# javascript paramenter object reference unknown

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following code (gutted to just the relevant code):

**JS**

```
function ToggleRow(objTwistie, objRow) {
  if (objRow.style.display == "none") {
    objRow.style.display = "";
    objTwistie.src = "../Images/SectionDown.gif";
  } else {
    objRow.style.display = "none";
    objTwistie.src = "../Images/SectionUp.gif";
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="./WelcomePage.aspx?Tab=2" id="form1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="MyTwistie1" onclick="ToggleRow (MyTwistie1,SubRow1)" src="../Images/SectionDown.gif" alt="alt">&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
              <div><span onclick="ToggleRow (MyTwistie1,SubRow1)" style="font-size:13px"><b>Header Row</b></span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="SubRow1">
      <td>
        This is the section that gets hidden
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

When I call the onclick event (click the image on the page) in the img tag, both object references are passed to the ToggleRow function properly, and the script operates properly.

However, when the event in the span onclick event is called, only the reference to objRow passes correctly and the reference to MyTwistie1 generates an error stating " 'MyTwistie1' is undefined". I realize that there are better ways to do this, but I just need to understand why this is failing.

Edit: The suggestion to use getElementById worked perfectly. If anyone can explain why it fails by just passing the ID by itself, that would be awesome.

Comment: Are `MyTwistie1` and `SubRow1` global variables? Where are they defined?

Comment: @brso05 - Due to some horrible traditions, those variables will be automatically defined because there are elements with IDs by that name.  IMO, this is a bad way to code.

Comment: @jfriend00 oh ok I didn't know that...Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It seems to be working well https://jsfiddle.net/c6crs8fy/

Comment: @mjorissen It only looks that way. The reference to SubRow1 is passed correctly and the section is hidden regardless of the element clicked. However the reference to the image only passes correctly when I click the image and the script that changes the image fails.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is there a more proper way to pass the ID of those elements (reference to their object)? In the real page, the image and the 'hide row' get generated dynamically so I can't code them directly in the scipt.

Comment: @DougSholly there are 2 ways you could either pass `id` to function or element itself directly. If you pass `id` then get element inside function before `if` conditions in functions or pass elements as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend replacing `MyTwistie1` with `document.getElementById('MyTwistie1')` and `SubRow1` with `document.getElementById('SubRow1')` in `onClick`  event call.